# php foreach loop show duplicate item

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop and have a problem with it. My loop show duplicate some item and I want show item only once and don't duplicate item. My loop it is.

```
  foreach($result as $res){
     $id    = $res->id;
     $title = $res->title;
     echo $title;
   }
```

Comment: can you show the SELECT query for this

Comment: did you try anything for that?if yes ,please show your code and contents in $result

Answer (score 3):

```
$partial=array();
foreach($result as $res){
if (!in_array($res->id, $partial)) {
   $id = $res->id;
   $title = $res->title;

   echo $title;
   array_push($partial, $res->id);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
$present_array = array();

foreach($result as $res){
   if(!in_array($res->title, $present_array)){
     $present_array[] = $res->title;
     $id    = $res->id;
     $title = $res->title;
     echo $title;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
function remove_dup($matriz) { 
    $aux_ini=array(); 
    $entrega=array(); 
    for($n=0;$n<count($matriz);$n++) 
    { 
        $aux_ini[]=serialize($matriz[$n]); 
    } 
    $mat=array_unique($aux_ini); 
    for($n=0;$n<count($matriz);$n++) 
    { 

            $entrega[]=unserialize($mat[$n]); 

    } 
    return $entrega; 
} 

foreach(remove_dup($result) as $res){
     $id    = $res->id;
     $title = $res->title;
     echo $title;
}
```

another solution is, if you are getting this data from database then use [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) in your select query.

Answer (score 0):

Do a fast check & make your code execute faster like this:

```
$check_dup = array();
foreach ($items as $item){
    if (in_array($item['id'], $check_dup))
        continue;
    else {
        array_push($check_dup, $item['sid']);

        /* your code in foreach loop */
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$result = array(
                array(
                    'id'        => "1",
                    'title'     => "My title"
                    ),
                array(
                    'id'        => "2",
                    'title'     => "My title 2"
                    )
                );

foreach($result as $res){
   $id = $res['id'];
   $title = $res['title'];
   echo $title . "<br>";
}
```